# Using 3rd party Apps in Django, some questions

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-apps

I am new to Django.

I have some doubts about installing 3rd party Apps in Django.

A specific example. The "django-registration" App in https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src. Reading the instructions the doc tell us to install this app with PIP(pip install django-registration), doing this the App will be installed in Python Site-packages, right?

My question is: The App must to be installed in that way? Why not put the 'django-registration' folder in our Project as an App?

PS: This is a starter Django Question.

Best Regards,

Comment: Have a look at [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html). See also this [blog post for a primer on virtualenv](http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I use virtualenv. But what I want to know is: The App must to be installed in that way? Why not put the 'django-registration' folder in our Project as an App?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with placing it in your project folder. IMHO, it just makes deploying your project and keeping the 3rd party apps up-to-date a little bit harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The App must to be installed in that way?

No.

As long as python can find it (ie: it's on the PYTHONPATH) you can put it any place you like.

> Why not put the 'django-registration' folder in our Project as an App?

Why not indeed?  If you plan on modifying it substantially that's perhaps quite reasonable.  If you aren't, then keeping it separate will keep it plain as to what is your code and what is not; and ease the updates to either.